My external monitor shows irregular colors for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

My external monitor shows the following colors when connected to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. The same Acer monitor works fine for Ubuntu 23.10.
I have seen a similar issue in this question, which currently does not have any answers.
Things I tried that did not work
I have tried changing color settings
ubuntu driver installation
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
xrandr--output DP-3 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
xrandr --output DP-3 --auto

Firstly I'd check the cable connections are secured perfectly, and you have a correct/working cable. You mention it works on an invalid Ubuntu release (there was no release in 2023-January or 23.01) but if you meant 23.10 there are different kernels involved which can be a clue (ie. check they're the same modules on each & not different modules; but same modules itself is a clue!)

thanks for comment @guiverc it was a typo ubuntu - 23.10. Same working cable works for 23.10
